# Obtener respuestas a un tweet específico en R con AcademicTwitteR

Tags: r, twitter-api

como dice el título, estoy tratando de obtener respuestas a un tuit específico por su ID con la API académica de twitter. Estoy tratando de hacerlo a través del parámetro conversation_id pero no obtengo ningún tweet.

```
tweets_data2 <- get_all_tweets(conversation_id = '1433573505593970703',bearer_token = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA....', n = Inf,)
```

Aclaro que la API funciona a la perfección para obtener tweets en función de queries textuales o por usuario.

¿Qué otra alternativa puedo tener para obtener lo que quiero?

Agradezco su ayuda de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Esto se debe principalmente a que la función necesita como parametro agregar `start_tweets` y `end_tweets`. Por ejemplo, si necesitas todos los tweets de esta conversación, puedes establecer un periodo de tiempo lo suficientemente largo como para abarcar todas los tweets.

Yo probé el siguiente código y me entrego 100 tweets con su respectiva metadata:

```
get_all_tweets(start_tweets = "2010-01-01T00:00:00Z",
               end_tweets = "2022-10-25T00:00:00Z",
               bearer_token = get_bearer(),
               conversation_id = "1433573505593970703")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]